# What is the meaning of the symbol \stackrel {<}{\neq} (or \lneqq)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the book Good Math by Mark C Chu-Carrol there is the following formula on page 130:
$$
x ∈ (A ∪ B) \lneqq x∈ A ∨ x ∈ B
$$
I don't know the name or meaning of this symbol and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

In the book it says the formula is a formal notation of set union.

So what does $$\lneqq$$ mean?

Comment: In another part of the book the subset symbol ia used and is different ( like the one you used ). It' s probably something else

Comment: It may be a typo.  The statements $x\in(A\cup B)$ and $x\in A\vee x\in B$ are logically equivalent.  Something like $$x\in(A\cup B):\Leftrightarrow x\in A\vee x\in B$$ would make more sense.  The symbol "$:\Leftrightarrow$" means "is equivalent by definition".

Comment: As his email is available through his blog, I just asked him. Hopefully we'll get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reiterate my previous deleted answer.

I've browsed your book [Mark Chu-Carroll, *Good Math A Geek's Guide to the Beauty of Numbers Logic and Computation* (2013)] until around page 150.

The symbols  $\stackrel {<}{\neq}$ is "clearly" used in the context of set opeartions, like : union, intersection and cartesian product, which usually are written as (e.g.union) :

> $x ∈ (A ∪ B) \Leftrightarrow x∈ A ∨ x ∈ B$.

The symbol "works" as a sort of "definitional equality" in the meta-language, like the symbol "$=_{def}$".

*I was **not** able to find in the first 150 pages, its definition/explanation ...*

Comment: I know what iff is. This symbol here is literally a minus than with a not equal to underneath

Comment: I know the book isn't just a transcription of the posts on Chu-Carroll's blog, but I thought it might be worth searching for blog posts discussing sets and union.  This [post](http://www.goodmath.org/blog/2007/05/16/set-theory-some-basic-definitions/) seems like it might be relevant.  It uses the double left-right arrow precisely as in Mauro ALLEGRANZA's answer.  But I don't have the book, so I can't check how much overlap there is between the material in the blog post and the passage in question.

Comment: from the blog post and everything this seem to be the correct answer. thank you!

Answer (score 5):

author here.

It's a typesetting error. It's supposed to be the if-and-only-if symbol, which looks like <=>.

I'm not sure why it was printed that way; in my pre-prints, it printed correctly. Getting the math stuff printing correctly in the book was a huge hassle - my publisher hadn't printed anything that had non-trivial math notation before.

I'm sorry that this slipped by. Hope knowing what it's supposed to look like helps!

Comment: All clear now! Thanks for the help